# Well-Ordering Theorem implies Hausdorff Maximal Principle

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I have a quick question regarding to the proof that well-ordering theorem implies Maximal Principle.
In the proof described here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Well-Ordering_Theorem_implies_Hausdorff_Maximal_Principle
The function is defined as

$$\rho(f:S_x \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X))\begin{cases} 
    f(S_x)\cup\ \{x\}  &\mathrm{if}\ P(S_x,x) \\
      f(S_x) & \mathrm{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}  $$

however, it doesn't seem to make sense to have
$$f(S_x)\cup\{x\}$$
as for example if one has $X$ as $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$
then
$$f(1)=\{1\}$$
$$f(2)=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$$
and so on.
Thus
$$f(S_3)=\{\{1\},\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\}$$
But I think the proof is intended to mean
$$f(S_3)=\{1,2\}$$
So shouldn't the function be defined as the following?

$$\rho(f:S_x \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X))\begin{cases} 
    \cup_{z \in S_x}f(z)\cup\ \{x\}  &\mathrm{if}\ P(S_x,x) \\
      \cup_{z \in S_x}f(z) & \mathrm{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}  $$

Answer (score 1):

No, $2\neq\{2\}$, so $X\cup\{2\}\neq X\cup\{\{2\}\}$. In other words, $\{1\}\cup\{2\}\neq\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$.

The proof is quite unclear, but here's the idea. Well-order your partial order. This well-order is not necessarily compatible with your partial order, of course. Now recursively go through the well-order, and start collecting elements into a chain: if you reached a certain point, and you've collected a chain so far, add an element if it is comparable to all the things you've collected so far.

At the end of the recursion process we have a chain, and we can prove it is maximal: if we could have added another element to it, why didn't we do it when we got to it on the well-ordering? Well, the only reason is that we couldn't really add it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still confused. I understand if the function $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2$ then $f(S_3)=\{1\}\cup\{1,2\}=\{1,2\}$, however the function defined in the proof is assigning the element to some set, not an element. That is, $f(S_3)=\{\{1\}\}\cup\{\{1,2\}\}=\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$. In other words, it's a set of sets. This kind of set would not satisfy the ideas you mentioned.

Comment: No, $f(S_x)$ is a chain. It's a subset of $X$. And if we can adjoin $x$ to it, then we do. Otherwise, we do not.

Comment: Thanks for the comments again. I understand it should be a chain for the proof to be consistent. But is the function defined above really forming a chain?

Comment: Yes. As I said, this proof is not very well-written. I'd suggest that you find a different proof that is easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you. I guess what I don't understand is the set operation $f(S_x)\cup\{x\}$. If $f(1)={1}$ and I don't even know how to define $f(2)=f(1)\cup\{2\}$. Is it $\{\{1\},2\}$ or $\{1,2\}$ or $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$? Is the image of $f(\{1,2\})$ equals to $\{\{1\},\{\{1\},2\}\}$ or $\{1,2\}$ or $\{1,\{1,\{2\}\}\}$?

Comment: But $f(1)$ is ***not*** $1$, it's $\{1\}$, and as we covered, $1\neq\{1\}$. I don't know what to add on what I already said. I'm sorry.

Comment: Correct. $f(1)=\{1\}$. So $f(2)=\{1\}\cup\{2\}=\{1,2\}$ then $f(S_3)=f(\{1,2\})=\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$ hence is not a subset of $X$, rather it is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ as expected from the definition. The problem happens when you form union $\cup_{x\in X}f(x)$ as the union is no longer a subset of $X$ rather it is a subset of the power set.

Comment: I have no idea how you got to $f(S_3)$ being $\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$. Please, either find a different proof to read, or wait for someone else to post an answer. I can't make my point any clearer than I already have.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that. But for the clarity. let us consider $A=\{1, 2\}$. By definition, $f(A)=\{f(x):x\in A\}$, which I hope you agree. Therefore $f(A)=\{f(1), f(2)\}$. Since $f(1)=\{1\}$ and $f(2)=\{1,2\}$, we get $A=S_3$ and $f(S_3)=\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$, which I hope I didn't make mistake.

Comment: Forget the formal presentation of this proof. *Really*. It is *not a well-presented proof*. Ignore it. Come back in three years once you've fully grokked the whole idea of a transfinite recursion and how this proof works, having repeatedly explained these sort of proofs to students. In the meantime, just find a better source. I have no other advice to offer you.